# Como verificar se existem processos async rodando

Tags: c#, winforms, async

Alguem conhece alguma maneira, de verificar se algum processo `Async` esta sendo executado?

Por exemplo, gostaria de fazer uma verificação, quando o usuário fechar o sistema, e não deixar fechar ate todos os processos `Async` estarem concluídos.

```
async public void EvokeMetodo(string contrato, int item,  bool editar)
    {
        //retorna um datatable contendo o iten que foi salvo ou editado
        DataTable Ret_Contrato = await Ret_Datatable(contrato, item);
        int verificador = 0;
        //insert
        if (!editar)
        {
            //retorna o numero de linhas afetadas, ou seja, o numero de insert feitos
            verificador = await Insert_ContratoItens(Ret_Contrato);

            if(verificador > 0)
            {
                atualiza_ContratoWeb(contrato, item);
            }
        }
        else//update
        {
            verificador = await Update_ContratoItens(Ret_Contrato);

            if (verificador > 0)
            {
                atualiza_ContratoWeb(contrato, item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tem como colocar esse trecho de código async que você está rodando?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Coloquei um trecho de um dos metodos `Async`, porem, temos varios metodos `Async` que são executados em telas diferentes, em momentos diferentes..

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira correta e mais eficaz de verificar isso é através de `Tasks`.

## 1. Transforme seu método em Task

Vamos transformar seu método em uma `Task` para que seja possível utilizar a diretiva `await`, caso queira esperar seu método executar para prosseguir.

```
private async Task EvokeMetodo(string contrato, int item,  bool editar)
{
    //retorna um datatable contendo o iten que foi salvo ou editado
    DataTable Ret_Contrato = await Ret_Datatable(contrato, item);
    int verificador = 0;
    //insert
    if (!editar)
    {
        //retorna o numero de linhas afetadas, ou seja, o numero de insert feitos
        verificador = await Insert_ContratoItens(Ret_Contrato);

        if(verificador > 0)
        {
            atualiza_ContratoWeb(contrato, item);
        }
    }
    else//update
    {
        verificador = await Update_ContratoItens(Ret_Contrato);

        if (verificador > 0)
        {
            atualiza_ContratoWeb(contrato, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Não é possível utilizar `await` em `void`, por isso criamos uma `Task`. Note que essa `Task` não está retornando nada, é como se fosse um `void` falando a grosso modo, pois ela vai apenas executar. Caso queira que o método retorne algo, apenas troque de `Task` para `Task<int>` e ela precisará que você retorne um `int`, por exemplo.

## 2. Execute a sua Task

Aqui iremos executar a sua `Task` (método) e armazenar a execução em uma variável `Task`, para que seja possível verificar seu status depois. Neste exemplo, coloquei a execução do seu método em um evento `Click` de um botão. Note que o método do `Click` do botão possui a diretiva `async`.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
   {
       await EvokeMetodo();
   });
}
```

Como utilizei await dentro da `Task.Run` para esperar a execução do método `EvokeMetodo`, é necessário utilizar uma expressão lambda com a diretiva `async()` para "invocar" o seu método e informar para o `Task.Run` que você quer esperar a execução do método que ele irá executar. Mais especificamente nessa parte:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
   await EvokeMetodo();
});
```

## 3. Verificando o status da sua Task

Se percebeu anteriormente, armazenamos a execução (retorno) do método `Task.Run` em uma variável do tipo `Task` chamada *task*. Através disso, é possível verificarmos o status da `Task`.

```
if(task.IsCompleted)
{
   // Faça alguma coisa
}
```

Além de `task.IsCompleted` temos também `task.IsCanceled` e `task.IsFaulted`.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que isso resolva, crie um variável Global com nome de asyncRodando e no  seu código async coloque

```
asyncRodando = true;
// CÓDIGO ASYNC AQUI
asyncRodando = false;
```

E na hora de fechar faça algo como.

```
{
if(asyncRodando)
return;

fecharPrograma();

}
```

Comment: Creio que resolva o problema.. mas seria a melhor forma? Não temos nenhuma propriedade no .NET que nos informe sobre processos `Async`?

Comment: Do modo que você está fazendo NÃO. MAS, Se você usar como TASK creio que tem uma propriedade chamada Status que informa se .IsCompleted, Segue -> https://www.dotnetperls.com/async